# tc command in linux does not work when capturing traffic with pcap

Tags: c, linux, pcap

I have a code in C that captures frames on an interface using pcap library. At the same time, I'm trying to play with the delays and losses on this interface using the tc (traffic control) linux tool. However, it seems that all the rules I set using tc have no effect when I capture the traffic with pcap. I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that pcap works at a very low layer (directly getting frames from the interface) while tc works at a higher layer. First I want to confirm if this is true. And if there is another way to simulate delays and losses in linux (without doing it programatically).